# Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: html, iframe, google-authentication

I have a this problem while trying to connect with google authentication to my site,
do you have any idea's  how to fix it ?

This is the error that I get :

Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Source code :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="position: relative; outline: none;" height="710" width="100%" src=" example " allow="geolocation example;" title="example " data-gtm-yt-inspected-12908112_11="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: you're trying to show it in a frame, which is not allowed. stop trying to add it in a frame and use redirection instead?

Comment: Thank you ,but ,what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I meet the same question like you. My manager needs me to find a way to combine 2 websites but not very time-consuming. So Iframe is the best potential way. But both of these 2 websites are using google oauth so it would jump to accounts.google.com which X-frame-options is deny. I suppose there isn't good way to solve iframe directly so I decide to change direction, using micro front-end.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).